# What is best way to write a org.wc3.dom.Element Java object to a javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter?

Tags: java, xml

I need to write org.wc3.dom.Element objects to a javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter.

I found exactly what I need in the [StaxUtils](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/StaxUtils.java.html) class of the [cxf-common-utilities jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-common-utilities), which has methods like

```
writeDocument(org.w3c.dom.Document d, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter writer, boolean writeProlog, boolean repairing) 
writeNode(org.w3c.dom.Node n, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter writer, boolean repairing) 
writeElement(org.w3c.dom.Element e, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter writer, boolean repairing, boolean endElement) 
etc..
```

However, this is a rather specific jar, having dependencies on the stax-api jar etc.. and I prefer to not use it.

I could write a utility based on the StaxUtils implementation myself, traversing the Element and doing writeStartElement(String), writeCharacters(String) and writeEndElement calls, but I'd rather use an existing utility class.

Does anyone know of some more basic xml util jar which contains similar methods, besides the cxf-common-utilities jar?
Or is there a simpler way to do this within the standard JDK classes that I am not seeing?

Comment: Did you look into the [XMLSerializer](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.html) class? This class is available in xerces.

Comment: I can't use that class for this use case. My requirement is to write org.wc3.dom.Element objects I get as input to a javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter. I can't change either type.

Comment: Just add your Element to a document without the XML declaration.

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean converting the Element to a String and using writeCharacters on the XMLStreamWriter: that does not work since all passed characters are escaped.
If you mean to not use XMLStreamWriter: well, I am not looking for alternatives.
I know about plenty of apis to write Elements to an OutputStream, to a File. Unfortunately, I am bound to use the XMLStreamWriter in this case.

Comment: I meant what you said.  By the way the [XMLStreamWriter](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) that you mentioned is from [Xerces-XML-Commons](xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi) project. So that is a single jar as you are looking.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an [identity `Transformer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer%28%29) from a `DOMSource` to a `StAXResult`. The source can be built from an `Element`, it doesn't have to be a complete `Document`.